# OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error using pyaudiowpatch

Tags: python, multithreading, pyaudio

I'm triying to record the audio output from my speackers using pyaudiowpatch in multiple segments but after the first audio file is recorded I get :

```
Exception in thread Thread-3 (record_audio):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\...\gui.py", line 24, in record_audio
    with open_audio_stream(default_speakers, wave_file) as stream:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\...\gui.py", line 67, in open_audio_stream
    stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyaudiowpatch\__init__.py", line 801, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyaudiowpatch\__init__.py", line 467, in __init__
    pa.start_stream(self._stream)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
```

the recording thread is killed before start recording again.

```
import pyaudiowpatch as pyaudio
import time
import wave
import threading

def record_audio():
    # Get the default speakers
    default_speakers = get_default_speakers()

    # Open the wave file
    wave_file = open_wave_file(default_speakers)

    # Set up the audio stream and callback
    with open_audio_stream(default_speakers, wave_file) as stream:
        # Print a message to indicate recording has started
        print_recording_message(default_speakers)

        # Continuously write audio frames to the wave file until the stop event is triggered
        while not stop_recording:
            time.sleep(0.1)

    # Close the wave file
    wave_file.close()

recording_thread = threading.Thread(target=record_audio)

def get_default_speakers():
    with pyaudio.PyAudio() as audio:
        try:
            host_api_info = audio.get_host_api_info_by_type(pyaudio.paWASAPI)
        except OSError:
            print_error_and_exit("WASAPI is not available on the system. Exiting...")

        default_speakers = audio.get_device_info_by_index(host_api_info["defaultOutputDevice"])

        if not default_speakers["isLoopbackDevice"]:
            for loopback in audio.get_loopback_device_info_generator():
                if default_speakers["name"] in loopback["name"]:
                    default_speakers = loopback
                    break
            else:
                print_error_and_exit("Default loopback output device not found. Exiting...")

        return default_speakers


def open_wave_file(default_speakers):
    wave_file = wave.open(filename+".wav", 'wb')
    wave_file.setnchannels(default_speakers["maxInputChannels"])
    wave_file.setsampwidth(pyaudio.PyAudio().get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
    wave_file.setframerate(int(default_speakers["defaultSampleRate"]))
    return wave_file


def open_audio_stream(default_speakers, wave_file):
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=default_speakers["maxInputChannels"],
                        rate=int(default_speakers["defaultSampleRate"]),
                        frames_per_buffer=audio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16),
                        input=True,
                        input_device_index=default_speakers["index"],
                        stream_callback=lambda in_data, frame_count, time_info, status: callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status, wave_file))
    return stream


def print_recording_message(default_speakers):
    print(f"Recording from: ({default_speakers['index']}){default_speakers['name']}")


def print_error_and_exit(error_message):
    print(error_message)
    exit()


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status, wave_file):
    wave_file.writeframes(in_data)
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)
```

I using two buttons in a basic gui, one for recording that creates a thread until the stop button stop it, when I click the recording button a second time the app stop working

Comment: And you verified that this library works on the OS you're using it on, and you've verified that your program has access rights/permissions to use the device(s) it's trying to connect to?

Comment: It works to record one file then stop working until I restart the app

Comment: And what did you already find about that error in relation to pyaudio for the OS you're using? (on that note: mention which OS you're on in your post, because that's rather important. The stack trace tells us it's Windows, but not which Windows)

Comment: It is Win 10. I found that the same error has appeared when people record from a microphone. But the solution not working for me.

Comment: remember to [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask), not (just) in a comment. Also it doesn't matter whether a solution you found worked (if it did, you wouldn't have posted a question =), but it _is_ important that you tell people what information you found (ideally, with links) and what _that_ did when you tried it. Not just "it didn't work" but talking about what errors or behaviour that yielded, so folks know what _not_ to ask you to do/recommend as fix.